# Open Camera app on Windows 10 using c# console?

Tags: c#, windows, camera

I want to make a very simple exe where it would open Windows 10 Camera app after displaying a messagebox.

From search, the thread says this and I tried: "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft.windows.camera:");" but I get error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'microsoft.windows.camera:' with working directory 'C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\Test\Test\bin\Debug\net6.0'. The system cannot find the file specified.'"

Another thread says to do this "await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("microsoft.windows.camera:"));" but I don't know what Launcher is.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: That post you saw that shows off the "Launcher" class has link to explain what it is.

Comment: Hi, sorry it does not. I added "Windows.System" before the Launcher and it says "The name 'Windows' does not exist in the current context". I'm really new in this.